# "Post 404 not found" with Rails and Api.ai

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks, dialogflow-es, ngrok

I'm making a webhook with **Ruby on Rails** to conect **Dialogflow** (api.ai) and **Telegram** with my application. I'm also using **Ngrok** on the webhook.

Everytime I write to the Telegram bot (token setted in Dialogflow fullfilment) the text is sent to Dialogflow to create a JSON request with the parameters I want. This is working.

The problem start when I want to receive this JSON on my app. I'm receiving this error:
[Ngrok configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz5RI.png)

Here is my **routes.rb**:

```
   # Telegram
   post "/#{Chamber.env.dialogflow.route}" => 'chatbot_users#webhook'
```

Here is my **dialogflow.yml**:

```
  dialogflow:
    url: 'https://XXXXXac.ngrok.io'
    route: 'webhook'
```

Here is my **chatbot_users_controller**

```
class ChatbotUsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def webhook
    p "-----------------------NOT REACHING THIS POINT--------------------"
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
      data = JSON.parse(request.body)
    else
      data = params.as_json
    end  
  end
end
```

If more code is needed, just ask.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: if you run `rake routes`, what do you get ?, do you see `/webhook` in that output ?.

Comment: `webhook POST     /webhook(.:format)`                                                                      `chatbot_users#webhook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can run `rake routes`, to see if the generated path has that actual naming.

I would suggest using `:as` in `routes.rb` when you declare the path. The `as` option lets you override the normal naming for the actually generated paths.

```
post "/#{Chamber.env.dialogflow.route}" => 'chatbot_users#webhook', :as => 'webhook'
```